# The space complexity of Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: space-complexity

I saw some textbook about the worst-case space complexity of Fibonacci Sequence. However, I have the following question:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about computer programming.  Perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a concrete example and generalize. Start with n = 5.

```
S(5) = S(4) + c
     = (S(3) + c) + c
     = ((S(2) + c) + c) + c
     = (((S(1) + c) + c) + c) + c

     = S(1) + 4c
```

There are 4 c's when n = 5. In general, there are n-1 c's.